# iPhone Safari doesn't rebind scroll event after pressing back button

Tags: scroll, jquery

I have a jQuery page-scroll event bound on page A, and a page-resize event.

I click through to page B.

I then press back to return to page A.

The resize event remains functioning, but the scroll event doesn't.

An example from someone else is here: http://nevue.net/a.htm.  Scroll a few times and you can see a number at the bottom updating on the scroll event.  Click on the number to go to google.  Then press back. On iPhone Safari this no longer updates.

I have tried rebinding the event by catching the back button press.  The following code goes on page A:

```
$(window).bind("pageshow", function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.persisted) {
        alert('just pressed back');
        $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
            alert('scrolling');
        });
    }
});
```

This code triggers the "just pressed back" alert when you return to the page, but the scroll event doesn't get rebound.

Does anyone know:

1. Why Safari keeps the resize event but not the scroll event?
2. How to re-bind the scroll event?